# Loading another page with jquery-Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, load

I am loading another html page from an index page, then I would like to get an element from that loaded page, but the page seems not loaded yet since the element resulted to null, even if there is a function call back with in the ajax load function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#btnEdit').click(function(){


    $('#contents').load("abcd.html",showNewcontents())


    function showNewcontents() {

        alert("" + document.getElementById("make").value);
    }

return false;

});
```

});

in body:

```
<body>

<a href="click me" id="btnEdit" name="btnEdit">CLICK ME </a>

<div id="contents"></div>

</body>
```

in abcd.html:

```
<div id="contents">


<form> 

<input type="hidden" id="make" name="make" value="make">

</form>


</div>
```

Any clue as to how to modify this to get the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load` expects to receive a function as an argument.

`showNewcontents()` **calls** a function.

You are passing the *return value* of the call to `showNewcontents`, not the `showNewcontents` function.

Remove the `()`.